# Django: Random ManyToMany relation is added on User connect

Tags: python, django

Strangest bug I ever encountered

User model is the regular one from `conrtib.auth.User`

Let's say I have the following model:

```
class Region(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    rakazim = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    goal = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and someplace else I have:

```
user_model = get_user_model()
rakaz = user_model.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

Then Immediately after the user creation method is called the "rakaz" instance has a random region connected

```
rakaz.region_set.all()  = [<random_region>]
```

It also sometimes connects to another model that has a similar `ManyToManyField` to `AUTH_USER_MODEL`

I debugged with pdb into the user creation method (in auth contrib) and immediately after calling save inside this happens.

AFAIK it happens only on the staging server, but until I find the reason I'm afraid to deploy to prod..

Django version 1.84. server using mariabdb on RDS

I don't use signals in my code (and at all :) ) and can't find relevant third party code doing this,  (And if so it would happen on my machine also)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be:
I seeded the staging server with data from prod for "region" the `dumpdata` command dumps the `region` with foreign keys for `rakazim` . But since the users where actually missing (I didn't copy the users from my prod environment) Instead of shouting at me, and not allowing me to `loaddata` with non existing foreign keys, `mariadb` chose to give me :+1 and add random foreign keys each time I created a user (Perhaps not random, but according to the imported mapping, not sure).

Lesson learned: use a proper DBMS and not a mysql varient.